# How to deploy jars to nexus with cmd

Tags: maven, cmd, nexus

I want to deploy some jars to sonatypenexus with cmd command. Can any one give me a sample code which is working?

Comment: because, I have hundreds of jars to deploy to nexus under different groupIDs and different artifactIds and different versionIDs. So need to automate it. :(

Comment: Do you have pom for them?

Comment: not yet. first of all I should have deploy them to nexus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this:
You can deploy jars to local and remote with deploy plugin.
http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html