# How to correctly put precompiled jars inside a maven project?

Tags: java, maven

There's a precompiled jar file. My sources depend on it. I need:

- This file should be added to classpath
- When I do `mvn deploy` without parameters, the file should be uploaded to remote repo
- When others use my project as a dependency, the file should be automatically downloaded from the remote repo and added to classpath
- I want this jar to have its own artifact id and pom file
- If possible, I'd like to keep the original jar name

I tried to put this in my pom:

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>pom-local</id>
        <url>file://${basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

Then wrote another pom.xml and put it and the jar file to `${basedir}/repo/`.
Strangely, according to google, nobody uses this. I didn't figure out how to keep the original jar name. And I can't make maven deploy it.

There's `attach-artifact` goal, but it requires a file name, not artifactId as the parameter and it puts the jar to the same folder.

Possible solution:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.foo</groupId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <artifactId>eeerrr</artifactId>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>pom-local</id>
        <url>file://${basedir}/repo</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>


<properties>
    <!-- Will use this instead of <distributionManagement>, because it's easier to extract url from one place -->
    <altDeploymentRepository>todo::default::http://0.0.0.0</altDeploymentRepository>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Extract url -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>extract-url</id>
                    <phase>verify</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>regex-property</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <name>deploymentRepository.url</name>
                        <value>${altDeploymentRepository}</value>
                        <regex>.*::(.*)</regex>
                        <replacement>$1</replacement>
                        <failIfNoMatch>true</failIfNoMatch>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- Upload additional artifact -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>deploy-3rd-party-jar</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy-file</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <groupId>org.foo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>eeerrr</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0</version>
                        <packaging>jar</packaging>
                        <file>${basedir}/repo/org/foo/eeerrr/1.0/eeerrr-1.0.jar</file>
                        <url>${deploymentRepository.url}</url>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Comment: Maybe you can deploy your jar in the repository and then include it like any other depedency. [Guide to deploying 3rd party JARs to remote repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html) But it will not be updated when you deploy your project. It will be an independent artifact.

Comment: I did a local project repo with jars once. I first put the jar in the normal .m2/repository using maven install commands, and then moved the directory. Still a dependency needed of course, for packing the jars together. Unfortunately long ago.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that this precompiled jar doesnt change that often.
You can just do a one time deploy to your local cached repo and remote repo using mvn install:install-file and mvn deploy:deploy-file.

Have a look at [How to deploy jars to nexus with cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25440663/how-to-deploy-jars-to-nexus-with-cmd/25441203#25441203), this is a similar question.